# CakePHP multiple ordering and paginate

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

I have a problem with cakephp pagination. I need to extract values from database and paginate them but have complicate conditions. First I need to sort events by date from a specific region and after that all ones and paginate them. Problem is that if I sort them in a view after pagination I get sorted by region and date but per page. So generally, I need first to show events from just one region by date and all the rest just by date and paginate them. 
E.G. Show first events from New York sorted by date and after that all the rest sorted by date no matter of region and need to paginate result.
How to create paginate query to get this kind of result?
Thanks ;)

```
     $this->paginate = array(
        'contain' => array(
            'Company' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'epic'),
                'limit'=>3,
                'PrimaryMarket'
            ),
            'City'
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Event.date >=' => date('Y-m-d')
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'BY FIELD(Event.region, \''.PAI_SUBDOMAIN.'\') DESC, Event.date ASC'

            ),
        'limit' => 6,
    );

    $events = $this->paginate('Event');
    $this->set('events', $events);
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I tried something like this: